# How do I fix C# Error cs0103 in Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, methods, syntax-error

I am working on a project that creates a simple perimeter and area calculator based on the values the user inputs. (For finding window perimeter and glass area). However, I'm stuck with 4 errors... all of which are CS0103. Can anyone help me fix these errors or clean up my code. I'm trying to separate everything into methods so I would like to keep the code in that general format.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp4
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            double totalLength, totalWidth, windowPerimeter, glassArea;

            //display instructions
            DisplayInstructions();

            // ask for width
            totalWidth = AskDimension();

            //ask for lenght
            totalLength = AskDimension();

            // calculate window Perimeter
            windowPerimeter = (2 * totalWidth) * (2 * totalLength);

            //calculate the area of the window & display output
            glassArea = totalWidth * totalLength;

            //calculate and display outputs

            Console.WriteLine("the lenth of the wood is " + windowPerimeter + " feet");
            Console.WriteLine("the area of the glass is " + glassArea + " square feet");
            Console.ReadKey();

            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        //display instructions
        public static void DisplayInstructions()
        {
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
            Console.WriteLine("This app will help you calculate the amount of wood and glass needed for your new windows!");
            Console.WriteLine("   ");
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
            Console.WriteLine("*Note* Please enter a height/width value between 0.01 - 100, all other values will cause a system error.");
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
            Console.WriteLine("   ");
        }

        //ask for width
        public static double AskDimension()
        {
            double totalWidth;
            const double MAX_HEIGHT = 100.0;
            const double MIN_Height = 0.01;
            string widthString;
            Console.WriteLine("please enter your height of the window");
            widthString = Console.ReadLine();
            totalWidth = double.Parse(widthString);
            if (totalWidth < MIN_Height)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("you enter vaule less than min width \n" + "using minimum one");
                totalWidth = MIN_Height;
            }
            if (totalWidth > MAX_HEIGHT)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("you enter value grater than Max height\n" + "using maximum one");
                totalWidth = MAX_HEIGHT;
            }

            return AskDimension();
        }

        //ask for height
        public static double AskDimension(string dimension)
        {
            double totalLength;
            const double MAX_HEIGHT = 100.0;
            const double MIN_Height = 0.01;
            string heightString;
            Console.WriteLine("please enter your height of the window");
            heightString = Console.ReadLine();
            totalLength = double.Parse(heightString);
            if (totalLength < MIN_Height)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("you enter vaule less than min width \n" + "using minimum one");
                totalLength = MIN_Height;
            }
            if (totalLength > MAX_HEIGHT)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("you enter value grater than Max height\n" + "using maximum one");
                totalLength = MAX_HEIGHT;
            }

            return AskDimension();
        }
        //calculate and display outputs
        public static double AskDimesnion(string windowPerimeter,
                                          string glassArea,
                                          string widthString,
                                          string heightString)

        {

            windowPerimeter = 2 * (totalWidth + totalLength);
            glassArea = (totalWidth * totalLength);
            Console.WriteLine("the lenth of the wood is " + windowPerimeter + " feet");
            Console.WriteLine("the area of the glass is " + glassArea + " square feet");
            Console.ReadKey();
            return AskDimension();
        }
}
}
```

Screenshot of errors in the method:
[image: Screenshot of errors in the method]

Comment: Why do you expect local variables from one method to be accessible in another method?

Comment: totalWidth & friends are scoped to main() - they cannot be accessed anywhere else.  Consider passing them around as individual arguments or as members of a class you pass.

Comment: Please **don't post errors as screenshots**. Post them as text.

Comment: Just a pointer, always Google your errors first along with language (without your specific variable names). Searching "C# the name does not exist in the current context" should have given you *way* more than enough.

Comment: Thanks Broots. I have Googled similar questions but I'm having trouble grasping what exactly I have to do and why. That's why I've posted it here.

Comment: Declare your variables (`totalLength, totalWidth, windowPerimeter, glassArea`) at the class level instead of inside of your main method.

Comment: I tried that and it makes the whole method a big error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The initial problem was that your variables weren't class scoped and also the calculations seem a bit crazy to me. But from pasting your code in to my editor I've had a quick tidy up and come out with the following:

```
using System;

namespace TestConsoleApplication
{
    class Program
    {
        static double _totalLength, _totalWidth, _windowPerimeter, _glassArea;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DisplayInstructions();
            _totalWidth = AskDimension("Height");
            _totalLength = AskDimension("Width");
            _windowPerimeter = (2 * _totalWidth) + (2 * _totalLength);
            _glassArea = _totalWidth * _totalLength;
            Console.WriteLine("The length of the wood is " + _windowPerimeter + " feet");
            Console.WriteLine("The area of the glass is " + _glassArea + " square feet");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        private static void DisplayInstructions()
        {
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
            Console.WriteLine("This app will help you calculate the amount of wood and glass needed for your new windows!");
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
            Console.WriteLine("*Note* Please enter a height/width value between 0.01 - 100, all other values will cause a system error.");
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
            Console.WriteLine();
        }

        private static double AskDimension(string dimensionType)
        {
            const double maxDimension = 100.0;
            const double minDimension = 0.01;

            Console.WriteLine($"Please enter your {dimensionType} of the window");

            var dimensionString = Console.ReadLine();
            var dimension = double.Parse(dimensionString);

            if (dimension < minDimension)
            {
                DisplayDimensionErrorAndExit("Min");
            }
            else if (dimension > maxDimension)
            {
                DisplayDimensionErrorAndExit("Max");
            }

            return dimension;
        }

        private static void DisplayDimensionErrorAndExit(string dimensionToShow)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"You entered a value less than {dimensionToShow} dimension");
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit");
            Console.ReadKey();
            Environment.Exit(0);
        }
    }
}
```

If a user enters invalid input the program will terminate, apart from that the calculations work and the correct output displayed.
If you've got any questions about it at all just ask me :-)

Comment: Thank you so much! Your solution was perfect! I noticed you changed it from 'public static double...' to private, can you explain how that works? Otherwise I understand your changes... I repeated myself a lot in the original code, I did not realize I could simplify it as such.

Comment: No problems at all, the method was changed to being ‘private’ as it’s only called from within the main class. Methods only need to be ‘public’ if you are going to expose them to other classes. You’re application is only a single class that works on its own methods so the methods could be made ‘private’, also notice that in your original code you were calling the method again instead of returning the object you stated in the method signature, this caused the original application to not work as intended . There’s a few cool things in there, string interpolation being one of them.

Answer (score 2):

Your `totalWidth` variable is not defined anywhere in your scope. It should be defined somewhere. Depending on where you exactly want to define it, you can do it internally in your **AskDimension** method or more globally. It seem by your logic it should be an input *parameter of your method*. Also you have other errors in your code. Your method is called ***AskDimesnion*** but you are calling it in your code by ***AskDimension*** (hopefully the correct method name...)

For variable scope, you can check [Microsoft's own documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973875.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the help. I fixed the spelling error. How would I define it internally of the AskDimension?